# How conditional render children widgets inside a stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to keep the drawerscreen in default and render the other screens in if else condition . How can i do that ? , Thanks in advance for the help `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget { 
  final String showScreen;
  
  const Body({
    Key key, 
    this.showScreen="map",
  }) : super(key:key);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      DrawerScreen(),
      MapScreen(),
      // PostScreen()
      ],
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this?

```
Widget _conditionedWidget(){
 if(condition)
   return MapScreen();
 else
   return PostScreen();
}
```

and then:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
  DrawerScreen(),
  _conditionedWidget(),
  ],
);
```

Comment: yeah something like this ,, let me try it .. thanks for the help